# SQL Ranking Dates to Get Year Over Year Order

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ranking, rank

I have a list of dates in a YYYYMM format and I am trying to rank them in a Year over Year format that would look like the following:

```
MonthDisplay  YearMonth  Rank  MonthNumber YearNumber
Aug-2013      201308     1     8           2013
Aug-2012      201208     2     8           2012
Jul-2013      201307     3     7           2013
Jul-2012      201207     4     7           2012
```

I have been able to get it close by using the following Rank and get the results below:

```
RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY MonthNumber DESC, YearNumber DESC)

Month     YearMonth  Rank  
Dec-2012  201212     1     
Dec-2011  201112     2     
Nov-2012  201211     114   
Nov-2011  201111     115   
Oct-2012  201210     227   
Oct-2011  201110     228
```

However, this starts with Dec-2012 instead of the Aug-2013 (current month). I can't figure out how to get it to start with the current month. I am sure it something super easy and I am just missing it. Thanks!

Comment: `RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY YearNumber DESC, MonthNumber DESC)`

Comment: That doesn't match the order listed in the first sample. It Ranks Aug-2013 as 1 and Aug-2012 as 13.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select
   T.YearMonth,
   rank() over (order by R.rnk asc, D.YearNumber desc) as [Rank],
   D.MonthNumber, D.YearNumber
from Table1 as T
    outer apply (
        select 
            month(getdate()) as CurMonthNumber,
            cast(right(T.YearMonth, 2) as int) as MonthNumber,
            cast(left(T.YearMonth, 4) as int) as YearNumber
    ) as D
    outer apply (
        select
            case
                when D.MonthNumber <= D.CurMonthNumber then
                    D.CurMonthNumber - D.MonthNumber
                else
                    12 + D.CurMonthNumber - D.MonthNumber
            end as rnk      
    ) as R
```

[**sql fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/39e1e/17) example

Comment: Same as above but without using _outer_ _apply_ 
`SELECT 
YYYYMM, 
RANK() OVER (ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN CAST(RIGHT(YYYYMM, 2) AS INT) <= Month(getDate()) THEN 
12 + CAST(RIGHT(YYYYMM,2) AS INT) - Month(getDate())
ELSE
CAST(RIGHT(YYYYMM,2) AS INT) - Month(getDate())
END DESC, 
CAST(LEFT(YYYYMM, 4) AS INT) DESC) AS Rank

FROM DateData`

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3c7f4/2

Comment: I'm using outer apply to avoid such a messy code like you have with million converts. You've repeated CAST(RIGHT(YYYYMM,2) AS INT) 3 times in your code and Month(getDate()) 3 times. Do you know about DRY principle?

Comment: Yes I agree. I like your solution much better than mine.